# Orthogonality of dot product is applicable only in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^7$

Tags: orthogonality

Does orthogonality of the dot product (i.e., If the dot product of two vectors is $0$ then they are orthogonal to each other) apply only in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^7$? The reason is that I also have come across videos using dot product, in the context of orthogonality, in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Hint:  it works in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Leo, that's the definition of orthogonality. For *each* dimenson.

Comment: Are you getting the dot product confounded with the cross product? The cross product is sometimes said to exist only in three dimensions or seven dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Often the definition of the angle between two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is based on the inverse cosine of their dot-product. That is, vectors are *defined* as being orthogonal if their dot product is zero.

Comment: It is clear now! Yes...I was getting confused with the cross product and dot product. Thank you, David. Other's comments were quite useful in further understanding the orthogonality. Thank you